# how to get desired row and with column names in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

**following is a preview of a marketing dataframe. Complete the code to get desired output**

```
   id  views  clicks
a  1   1000   300
b  2   1200   800
c  3   800    200
```

**output**

```
   views  clicks
a  1000   300
```

**what should i change in my code to get this output**

```
import pandas as pd
market=pd.read_csv("marketing.csv")
print(market.iloc[0])
```

Comment: What output u get now.?

Comment: i get first row as my output with column names

Comment: no all the columns are named in that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use iloc like this for your purpose. But you will get a Series

```
market.iloc[[0], [1, 2]]
```

or `loc` like this to get a dataframe

```
market.loc[['a'], ['views', 'clicks']]
```

Comment: iloc is not printing a

Comment: loc command is showing an error

Comment: @Ayushimidha You need to pass a list of rows for it to show a DataFrame instead of a Series. See the edit.

Comment: loc is still showing error

Comment: iloc command is giving the desired output

Comment: @Ayushimidha I am getting the desired output with loc. What is your pandas version.?